# How to debug Private Method in Developer Console

Tags: apex, class, access-modifier, private

I have a private method with parameter,
How can i debug the below code using Developer Console.
Example :

```
public class TestExam {   
     public static void updateRecord(String name) {

      }
   }
```

Debug: TestExam.updateRecord('Test');

```
public class TestExam {   
     private static void updateRecord(String name) {

      }
   }
```

Debug : ?

Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `@TestVisible` annotation to allow test methods to access private or protected members of another class outside the test class.

```
public class TestExam {   
    @TestVisible Private static void updateRecord(String name) {

    }
}
```

After adding this annotation you can continue with your current test class and you should now see the parameters of the private method. Take a look at the [TestVisible Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) documents if you want to understand further.

Comment: @TSmith..I know TestVisible Annotation Process . but my question is ,is possible to debug private method in developer console like public method(TestExam.updateRecord('Test');.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I am not aware of any accessing to private members through test classes unless you use the @TestVisible annotation. AFAIK Developer console does not give you any extra capabilities for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Or for development purpose as well as debug purpose, you can expose private method as public method and on later stage convert it back to public method.

Answer (score 0):

In Apex we can't debug private methods, but we can call private method in another method with in the same class.

```
public class privatemethodclass{
private static string getname(string name){
system.debug(name);
return name;
}
public static void saveacc(){
string nameee = privatemethodclass.getname('Test1234');
system.debug(nameee);
}  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Developer Console** is just a *web editor* that is developed upon the Salesforce *Tooling API* and *Metadata API*, just like **Force.com IDE** or **Mavensmate**

Private method in **Apex** is invisible outside of the containing class interdependently from the editor